# Xcode: Determine which UI element is triggering segue

Tags: xcode, segue

We have created a segue from a `UITableViewCell` in scene A to show scene B.  How can you see that relationship in Xcode?

In Xcode we can select the source scene, look at Utilities \ Connections Inspector and see the segue.  The storyboard shows the link between scene A and B.  But I can't see how you can determine that the `UITableViewCell` in scene A is the UI element which triggers the segue.

Comment: Try to select the segue, and the UI element which triggers the segue should be highlighted in scene A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select the segue in the outline view you can see the linkage:

[image: segue outline view]

The outline view is shown with by clicking this image in the bottom left corner of the storyboard editor:

[image: icon]

Answer (score 0):

The segue is not hooked up automatically to your table view by creating it in the Storyboard. A segue is just information that says we can transition from view A to view B. You've got to manually kick it off in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` with a call to `performSequeWithIdentifier:`, passing in the value you've set for the Identifier field for the segue in your Storyboard.

Comment: I posted an answer below...   Does appear that there is a linkage with the scene element.